# GStreamer USB 2.0 webcam

Tags: usb, webcam, gstreamer

Hello i'm trying to test GStreamer on OpenSuse 11.4, to display a webcam, but it says

> # gst-launch v4l2src ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv,height=240 ! xvimagesink
>
> > Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...  Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...  Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...  New clock:
> >     GstSystemClock
> >     libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: No such device ...  ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed trying to
> >     get video
> >     frames from device '/dev/video0'.  Additional debug info:
> >     v4l2src_calls.c(200): gst_v4l2src_grab_frame ():
> >     /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed after 50 tries.
> >     device /dev/video0. system error: No such device Execution ended after
> >     7995625828 ns. Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Setting pipeline to
> >     READY ... libv4l2: error turning off stream: No such device
> >
> > (gst-launch-0.10:19771): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: Failed to deactivate
> >     pad v4l2src0:src, very bad Setting pipeline to NULL ... libv4l2: error
> >     turning off stream: No such device
> >
> > (gst-launch-0.10:19771): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: Failed to deactivate
> >     pad v4l2src0:src, very bad Freeing pipeline ...

Thanks for help.

I also got the error message :

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>   ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed getting controls attributes on device '/dev/video0'.
>   Additional debug info:
>   v4l2_calls.c(267): gst_v4l2_fill_lists (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
>   Failed querying control 9963776 on device '/dev/video0'. (5 - Input/output error)
>   Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>   Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: Do you have /dev/video0? Why don't you do a ls of /dev and check. Perhaps your camera is on another device. You can specifiy the device in v4l2src options.

Comment: Yes, i have /dev/video0.

Comment: The closest I came to finding something similar out there was http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-uvc-devel@lists.berlios.de/msg04787.html. However this may not be applicable to your case. Check out the whole thread once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the output of v4l-info would be useful to diagnose such problems. Also the warn/info level of GST_DEBUG. Anyway, better file a bug and attache the logs there.

Besides for the sake of isolating the problem, start with the simplest pipline:
gst-launch v4l2src ! xvimagesink